# StreamWriter failing to run after 1st iteration in for loop

Tags: c#, html-parsing, streamwriter

I'm having issues using StreamWriter to code a scraper for a current project i've got. The loop i've coded is below

I've debugged all the variables coming into the loop and everything is set as it should be. When i pass in a url and the range to search through based on an ID GET variable in the url it fails to write the second sourceCode string

Could someone be kind enough to tell me if i'm not flushing something or is there something else at work here??

I've wrecked my head trying to find the root cause but its proving very stubborn

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Scraper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Scraper scraper = new Scraper();
        private StreamWriter sw;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            string[] urlBits = url.Split('.');
            string[] domain = urlBits[2].Split('/');

            string filepath = @"C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\"+urlBits[1]+"-"+domain[0];
            string parentPath = @"C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\";
            string newPath = Path.Combine(parentPath, filepath);

            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {}
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            string curDate = String.Format("{0:ddd-MMM-dd-yyyy}", today);
            string subPath = newPath + "\\" + curDate;
            string newSubPath = Path.Combine(newPath, subPath);

            if (File.Exists(subPath))
            { }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newSubPath);
            }

            string lower = textBox2.Text;
            int lowerValue;
            int.TryParse(lower, out lowerValue);

            string upper = textBox3.Text;
            int upperValue;
            int.TryParse(upper, out upperValue);

            int i;
            for (i = lowerValue; i < upperValue; i++)
            {
                string filename = newSubPath+"\\Advert-"+i+".html";
                string adPage = url + i;
                bool write = scraper.UrlExists(adPage);
                if (write)
                {
                    string sourceCode = scraper.getSourceCode(adPage);
                    using (sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
                    {
                        sw.Write(sourceCode);
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Scrape Complete");

        }
    }
}

####This is the Scraper Object
using System.Net;

namespace Scraper
{
class Scraper
{
    WebClient w = new WebClient();
    public bool UrlExists(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string getSourceCode(string url)
    {
        string s = w.DownloadString(url);
        return s;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, your calls to Close and Dispose aren't necessary, with your using block.

Comment: I the if(write) returning true on the second pass? Seems like the {0}\Advert-{1}.html url possibly didn't exist.

Comment: The problem you have has nothing to do with StreamWriter; removing all the code that you haven't provided complete code for (like scaper, url) and just make sourceCode random text; StreamWriter works fine.

Comment: Provide the error you get, or provide an complete example that shows reproduces the problem.

Comment: There is no error generated at all, thats the problem. The if(write) condition is satisfied on the second iteration and retrieves the sourceCode but it fails to write it to its designated file

Comment: `Path.Combine` does not do what you think it does. It will combine the two paths if the second argument is a relative path. According to the documentation for `Path.Combine`: `If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.` Are you sure you're getting the correct paths?

Comment: @SPFiredrake it appears so.I've debugged my way through to check the paths and they appear correct. The first file writes perfectly but as stated when it gets to iteration two,when it gets to the StreamWriter it doesn't write or proceed or throw an error,totally bemused

Comment: For the sake of debugging, can you get the values of `adPage` and `filename` for each iteration and add it to your question? It can be relative to some base path if you don't want to provide too much information. Also, can you post up the `filepath`, `parentpath`, `newpath`, `subpath` and `newsubpath` before you hit `for` loop?

Comment: Here you go:
Filepath:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\monaghanbros-co
ParentPath:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\
Newpath:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\monaghanbros-co
Subpath:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\monaghanbros-co\Sat-May-12-2012
Newsubpath:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\monaghanbros-co\Sat-May-12-2012
Filename:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\monaghanbros-co\Sat-May-12-2012\Advert-2690.html
AdPage:http://www.monaghanbros.co.uk/details.asp?CarID=2690
Filename:C:\Users\Herbaldinho\Desktop\monaghanbros-co\Sat-May-12-2012\Advert-2691.html
AdPage:http://www.monaghanbros.co.uk/details.asp?CarID=2691

Comment: Just a note, the adPages actually are prefixed with http://www but the forum appears to be converting that to hyperlink format

Comment: I've been debugging again today and after leaving the app running for approx 5 mins it returns a timed out error during the second iteration,does this help anyone understand what is going on better? I'm still at a loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem this morning
For anyone else having a similar problem, the try catch logic in the UrlExists method needs to close the response (response.Close())
From what i had understood it autoclosed but this is not the case
Hope this helps

Many thanks for the responses in helping me resolve this everyone